# Ultra thin skin of cured resin found floating in vat, possible sources?

Tags: troubleshooting, fdm, resin

I've been repeatedly finding small fragments of extremely thin cured resin floating in the vat of my elegoo saturn resin printer.

They're maybe a couple of CM across and so thin that I can't measure them. Thinner than the thinnest Suran wrap by at least half. They're very delicate and flexible so they haven't caused any damage, but I don't know where they are coming from.

I've cleaned my vat between each print, and used new resin, but it's happened 3 time now so it looks like it's being generated when I do a print run rather than coming from an old bottle.

Is this a known issue?

[image]

**EDIT**

This seems to be forming on or around the skate that supports the model, and probably only during the forming of the bottom layers. Large skates seem to form thicker chunkier "bits" while small skates form thin skins.

Is it possible that this is some kind of light spill during the bottom layer only?

The rest of my models seem to come out perfectly, so whatever is happening does not seem to be happening on every single layer.

I ran my printer for about 10-15 layers without a vat in place, and couldn't see anything unusual with the naked eye.

Comment: can you share a photo? That sounds like either it is a film that is ripped free from somewhere (your screen protector?) or a problem with your screen at times flickering and letting light through.

Comment: It's 100 percent definitely resin due to its color being distinctive, I'm not sure a picture will help, it's just a thin layer of semi cured resin about 10 by 15 mm.

Comment: A photo of the floating slices would suffice, just so we can try to see what you see

Comment: It's a little crumpled up, but this is it.

Comment: Are you experiencing any light ingress, either from the cover being removed or dislodged? Stray UV light of low intensity or extremely short exposure might cause this but it would have to be a very peculiar situation, a reflection from a shiny UV reflective surface?

Comment: Could it be a layer that didn't attach to a print?

Comment: The prints came out perfectly and are dungeons and dragons figure s so the only part that is large enough on them is the base, it's probably not light ingress as I store my printer with a  blackout cover over the top.

Answer (score 1):

If your prints are coming out OK and you do not see obvious failures, then it's most likely that your screen started leaking light. In general, LCD screens does not fully block UV light and some does get through even through "dark" pixels. With time it gets worse and more and more light is able to get through the screen. At some point, that parasitic light becomes enough to cure some resin over a longer printing time. And this is what you are seeing. The only solution to this is to replace your LCD screen with a new one.

Answer (score -1):

Thats not good.
I've been having the same issues and my Photon Mono X is only 6 prints in from being new.
I was chalking it up to the newb way I was cleaning my FEP and the scratches that are letting light spread everywhere. I am changing my FEP today to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/16461)

Comment: Hi and welcome. This answer seems to be a cross between a "me too" type comment and a speculative fix (which, again, would serve better as a comment). Please [edit] and update your answer with a definitive solution as soon as you are able, otherwise this answer *may* be converted to a comment under the question... Also, please take the [tour].

Comment: I think that what they're trying to say is that the problem could be being caused by a scratches on the FEP causing resin to cure unevenly?

Comment: Any update on whether the FEP change fixed the issue? If so (or not), please [edit] and update the answer. Otherwise your answer may be deleted or converted to a comment